# li element not expanding to height of ul element when one li element pushes height of ul

Tags: css, list, navigation, html-lists

I am trying to get all my li elements to take up the entire height of the ul element that contains them then align all li element contents to bottom.

I can't get passed the first part, when i have an image in one of the li elements the other li elements wont expand to be same height.

Here is my html

```
<nav id="sliderNav">
<ul id="sliderWrap">
      <li>wow 1</li>
      <li>wow2<br /> cool
      </li>
      <li>
          <img src="blank-trans.png" width="290" height="417" />
      </li>
      <div class="clearfloat"></div>
    </ul>
</nav>
```

My simple css is

```
#sliderNav{
    text-align:center;
    background-color:#000;
}
#sliderNav ul{
    list-style:none;
    display:inline-block;
    background-color:#0F0;
    height:100%;
}
#sliderNav ul li{
    display:block;
    float:left;
    height:100%;
    background-color:#C3C;
}
```

What i get is this:
[image: Image showing the problem]

Comment: If you don't absolutely need #slidernav ul to be height:100% but rather a specific px amount it seems to work as you want.

Comment: The issue is i am not always sure what the picture height will be thus i can not set a height as it may change

Answer (score 1):

a couple of issues:

- Setting the height:

You cannot set the height of an element to 100% if its parent doesn't have an explicitly set height.

- Aligning the content to the bottom:

The best way to align the content to the bottom is to put it in a container that's positioned absolutely and set the 'bottom' to '0'. this could complicate things with your current markup, so...

My solution:

via jQuery (or you can use any library or plain javaScript) Loop through all the li's and grab the height of the tallest one, and store it in a variable:

```
maxHeight = 0;
$("li").each(function() {
     maxHeight = maxHeight > $(this).height() ? maxHeight : $(this).height();
})
```

After you get the tallest one, loop through the li's again and set a top padding which equals to maxHeight (tallest li) - height of curent li . This will not only make all the li's the same height but it will also align the content automatically to the bottom of the li:

```
$("li").each(function() {
    $(this).css('padding-top', maxHeight - $(this).height() + 'px');
})
```

I have fiddled this for you:

http://jsfiddle.net/egrBV/2/

I added a right border to the li so you can see how they're divided up.

hope that helps

Comment: Wow, Thanks for the quick response.... Does anyone know of a CSS only way to accomplish this though as i want to have the look even if someone has javascript off